# Changing a string in a json object

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to update a json file and I'm using laravel command to do it. In that file there are specific product codes that need to be changed. The code I'm doing to do this isn't working, it runs but nothing changes.

Here is my code

```
$old_code = 'P001';
$new_code = 'P011';

$productJson = json_decode(file_get_contents(storage_path('/Product 1/product.json')));

foreach($productJson as $key => $value){
    str_replace($old_code, $new_code, $k);
}

file_put_contents(storage_path('/Product 1/product.json), json_encode($productJson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

and this is my json file

```
{
    "P001": {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "price": "200",
        "category": "Shirts"
    },
    "P002": {
        "name": "Product Test",
        "price": "100",
        "category": "Tops"
    },
}
```

Comment: [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) does nothing by itself, it _returns_ results. Also, that "subject" `$k`, where would that be defined in your code?

Comment: And WHAT IS `$k`

Comment: Seems to me you need to Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: It would also be useful to have been shown an example of the file that you are processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I've updated my question to include my json file

Comment: That is invalid JSON though

Comment: And just in case you missed it, `storage_path('/Product 1/product.json)` is missing a closing quote `'`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? You should check whether opening the original file, parsing it to JSON, replacing stuff, writing the file, or something completely else fails

Answer (score 0):

Its probably simpler to read the file and create a new JSON with the new codes like this

```
$s = '{"P001": {
  "name": "Product 1",
  "price": "200",
  "category": "Shirts"
},
"P002": {
  "name": "Product Test",
  "price": "100",
  "category": "Tops"
},
"P003": {
  "name": "Product Test",
  "price": "50",
  "category": "Bottoms"
}
}';
 
$old_codes = ['P001', 'P002' ];
$new_codes = ['P011', 'P022' ];

$productJson = json_decode($s);

$new = new stdClass;

foreach($productJson as $key => $json){
    $kk = array_search($key, $old_codes);
    if ( FALSE !== $kk ) { // found
        $new->{$new_codes[$kk]} = $json;
    } else {
        $new->{$key} = $json;
    }
}

echo json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

//file_put_contents(storage_path('/Product 1/product.json'), json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

RESULT

```
{
    "P011": {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "price": "200",
        "category": "Shirts"
    },
    "P022": {
        "name": "Product Test",
        "price": "100",
        "category": "Tops"
    },
    "P003": {
        "name": "Product Test",
        "price": "50",
        "category": "Bottoms"
    }
}
```