# How to update the 3rd level of a json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have a json file that looks like this

```
{
    "PL001": {
        "player_name": "Player 1",
        "player_email": "playeremail@email.com",
        "hobbies": {
          "SP001": {
            "sport": "Soccer",
            "positions": {
              "FL1":{
                "position": "Goalie"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    },
    "PL002": {
      "player_name": "Player 2",
      "player_email": "playeremail2@email.com",
      "hobbies": {
        "SP002": {
          "sport": "Hockey",
          "positions": {
            "FL2":{
              "position": "goaltender"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is change my positions codes to my new ones so for example my FL2 will be PLFL2

I've managed to get to the positions code but I'm not sure as to how I should go about pushing the new code up without loosing data.

Here is my codes

```
$old_code = "FL2";
$new_code = "PLFL2";


$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(storage_path('/players.json')));

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value->hobbies as $hobbiesCode => $hobby) {
        foreach ($hobby->positions as $positionCode => $position) {
            $positionCode = $new_code;
        }
    }
}
```

and that is where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to now go and update my json file with the new codes

Comment: Are you the [same person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505363/changing-a-string-in-a-json-object/63506266#63506266) or in the same class?

Comment: No I'm not the same person

Answer (score 0):

If `FL2` is the only code you want to change you can just use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on the value returned by `file_get_contents`

```
$json_string = file_get_contents(storage_path('/players.json'));

$json_string = str_replace("FL2", "PLFL2", $json_string);

file_put_contents($json_string);
```

If not, if you want to replace all the `FL{number}` to `PLFL{number}`, you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$json_string = file_get_contents(storage_path('/players.json'));

$json_string = preg_replace("/FL(\d)/", "PLFL$1", $json_string);

file_put_contents($json_string);
```